# Get a discord users pfp without discord.py in python

Tags: python, discord

I would like to get a users avatar link with their user id without using discord.py

Is there an alternate library?

Comment: This is like asking how to blend up strawberries without using a blender. Sure, it's doable, but you'll need a sharp knife, a steady hand, and a *lot* of free time. Why don't you want to use discord.py? It's literally made for this

Comment: If you're looking for a package in another language... look at their docs? It's a quick google search. If you looking for another package in python, interact with the discord's API yourself. I don't know why you wouldn't want to use discord.py as it does all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rich embed for discord.js this should be your code

```
const embed = new controller.RichEmbed()
  var user = message.user;
  var useravatar = message.user.avatarURL;
  embed.setAuthor(`This was requested by ${tk}`, useravatar);
  embed.setTitle("Current Inventory");
  embed.addField(`Wardrobe:`,`Pink hair, choker, pink and white striped hoodie, and ripped black jeans`);
  embed.addField(`Invenory:`,`Bat with nails, Medkit, ||secret knife|| `);
    embed.setColor('#b89870');
    bot.reply(message, embed);
```

but you probably wanna know what gets the avatar url,
first we declare our variable

```
var useravatar = message.user.avatarURL;
```

Then we use it in our embed as an image

```
embed.setAuthor(`This is plain text, the next slot is for the image url grabbed from discord`, useravatar);
```

Anything that states you can put a url in discord.js, you can put a variable.

Comment: Please fix the strings.

Comment: I added backticks so i can use my variables with ${}, if you want to use it without the back ticks, you can simply use double or single quote(s)